# Updating a List[List[Int]] with specific elements

Tags: scala

I have these two items:

1) `grid:List[List[Int]`      which represents a table full of numbers

2) `x:List[(Int,Int, Int)]`   where the first two Ints are row and column coordinates and the last what the specific location must be updated with.

Basically,I need to update the grid with the following items in list x, without using loops or vars.

This is where I have arrived till now, but It doesn't work.

```
def changeItem(x:(Int,Int,Int)) ={
        grid.apply(x._1).updated(x._2, x._3)
}
z.map(x => changeItem(x)) //z contains the list[(Int,Int,Int)]
```

Am I on the right track?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yet another question from a Sudoku solver assignment? It would be interesting to see the assignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use `map` to do this since `map` changes `grid` according to the things in `x`, which would presumably return a list of modified `grid`s, each with one change.  Instead you want each thing in `x` to modify the whole of `grid`, to hold onto this modified `grid`, and to perform the next change on the updated grid, and so forth.  The `map` method can't do this, but `foldLeft` can since it carries each operation's result forward to the next operation.

```
val grid = List(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6),List(7,8,9))
val x = List((2,0,11),(1,2,12),(0,0,13))
x.foldLeft(grid) { case (z, (i,j,v)) => z.updated(i,grid(i).updated(j,v)) }
// List[List[Int]] = List(List(13, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 12), List(11, 8, 9))
```

So the update statement says to replace `grid`'s `i`th element with an updated version of `grid(i)` (since we have to put the same list back in its place after modification) where the `j`th element is replaced with `v`.

Comment: Cool, didn't know you could do that with FoldLeft. I'll give it a try, thanks a lot for the quick reply! :)

Comment: or if you want to update the grid in place, just use foreach.